# Using a mdf file from SQL Server 2019 in a Visual Studio 2019 C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, localdb, sql-server-2019

I've attached `.mdf` files to Visual Basic applications plenty of times. I'm not 100% new to C#, I know some about it. I also know that attaching a `.mdf` is similar enough. I ran into this during my senior project, see below.

[image]

I just got SQL Server 2019 yesterday, and my Visual Studio (Community edition) is updated to the most recent patch as well. Side note: I just made a few tables with some example data in them to see if I could get it to work. Any advice on what to do?

EDIT: While looking through my visual studio installations, it seems I have localdb 2016... no options for 2019. So my question now evolves to:

How can I get Visual Studio to use a 2019 version of LocalDB?

Comment: You need to [download SQL Server 2019 Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15), install it, and then use its connection string (i.e. instance name) to connect your VS project to it.

Comment: Your connection string is wrong.  You should not be using a LocalDB (an attach) in connection string when the database is already attached to a server.  You should delete the Attach Statement to the connection string since database is already on a server.  The use the database name and instance in the connection string.  If you open the database in SQL Server Management Studio the login window will show the Server Name and Instance of the Server.

Comment: If you want to use the same database in the LocalDB, I don't recommend that you use attach mdf files to do it. I suggest that you can generate the database scripts from the sql server 2019, and execute the scripts in the LocalDB directly. You can refer to [Steps to Generate Database Scripts With Data In SQL Server](https://dzone.com/articles/generate-database-scripts-with-data-in-sql-server) to do it.